# Upload image to database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to figure out how I can upload a profile image to my database within my asp.net mvc web project.

The issues is that im getting a Data URI instead of an actual file upload and that the URI is generated inside my javascript and im not sure how I can pass URI aswell as the other input fields inside my form to the controller.

**View - *Form***

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProfilePicture, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="image-editor">
                    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
                    <div class="cropit-preview"></div>
                    <div class="image-size-label">
                        Resize image
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls-wrapper">
                        <div class="slider-wrapper">
                            <span class="icon icon-image small-image"></span>
                            <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input custom">
                            <span class="icon icon-image large-image"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="hidden" name="profilePicture" class="hidden-image-data">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Javascript below the Form**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.cropit.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.image-editor').cropit({
            imageBackground: true,
            imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 20,
            initialZoom: 'image',
            smallImage: 'stretch',
            imageState: {
                src: '/Images/ProfilePictures/no-img.png'
            }
        });
        $('form').submit(function () {
            var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
            // imageData containing the Data URI for the cropped image
            $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller - Register**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register([Bind(Exclude = "ProfilePicture")]RegisterViewModel model) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {

                // To convert the user uploaded Photo as Byte Array before save to DB 
                byte[] imageData = null;
                if (Request.Files.Count > 0) {
                    HttpPostedFileBase poImgFile = Request.Files["ProfilePicture"];

                    using (var binary = new BinaryReader(poImgFile.InputStream)) {
                        imageData = binary.ReadBytes(poImgFile.ContentLength);
                    }
                }
.... more code ....
}
}
```

Feel free to ask for more explanatory details.

Answer (score 0):

A data URI is a non-binary encoding of binary data. That is the data you want.

It's probably base64 encoded so you can just base64 decode it on the server side before you write it.

There's [code here to encode into and from base64](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/blog/blogentry=000361/blogentry.aspx)

Here's the example code from the site linked above:

```
public class Base64Decoder
{
      public static void Main ()
      {
            string inputText = "This is some text.";
            Console.Out.WriteLine ("Input text: {0}", inputText);
            byte [] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (inputText);

            string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String (bytesToEncode);
            Console.Out.WriteLine ("Encoded text: {0}", encodedText);

            byte [] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String (encodedText);
            string decodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (decodedBytes);
            Console.Out.WriteLine ("Decoded text: {0}", decodedText);

            Console.Out.Write ("Press enter to finish.");
            Console.In.ReadLine ();

            return;
      }
}
```